# Need to add a comment section in material table by making a colspan or any suitable approach

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to add a colspan in material table i have the below code for the table.

The html code for the table is as below, where i need a section for adding comments for each row on clicking of + button as shown in the drawing.

Table.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <div>
      {{element.name}} 
      </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
       <button *ngIf="!isEdited" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button> </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <button *ngIf="isEdited" mat-mini-fab class="add-btn" matTooltip="Add comment" color="primary">+</button>
      <button *ngIf="isEdited" mat-mini-fab class="add-btn" color="warn">-</button>
       </td>
    </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
<div *ngIf="isEdited" class="action-btn">
  <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Add comment" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">Save</button>
</div>
```

**Table.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol','actions'];
  isEdited:boolean;

  dataSource =[
    { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
    { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
    { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onEdit(){
    this.isEdited = true;
  }

  onCancel(){
    this.isEdited = false;
  }
}
```

[image]

On click of + button need to add the comment section in mat table..

Please find the below stackblitz link for the table[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfgocy?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts)

Comment: You just want to add a comment means no need of editing Name & Weight columns...? I think its better to not use colspan or rowspan because you have position numbers when we add new row at specific index(after clicking + icon) we have to adjust position numbers which is not a good practice.

Comment: When we click on + icon new pop up kind of thing will appear & we can add comment. Is this approach ok for you?

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI, yeah we can edit the name and other fields too, but i was not able to do the comment field,  the comment field is an Input field which spans through all the columns..i.e. name, weight and symbol column.. i was not sure how to achieve  that so this question... i have attached a pic for my comment field which spans through the columsn

Comment: is that link helped or you need more custom manner?

Comment: this link might help...https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-es19ub?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @PALLAMOLLASAI for the answer, but i was not looking for the popup kind of element for comment, i wanted to have a field which spans all the column in the material table.. please see the drawing in blue above, which is the comment field.. i was looking something in that manner

Comment: Could you please tell you are still looking for solution right? Im working on it present otherwise I won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working a lot i have developed the above in somewhat different manner. You can check once.(When you click on + or - icon a new comment section will be created & deleted viceversa.)

1) Go to this link & paste whole mentioned code below.

[Add dynamic row using multiTemplateDataRows](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfgocy?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts)

**table-basic-example.html code**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8"> 

 <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element.position}} </td>
 </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
 <ng-container matColumnDef="name" [attr.colSpan]="2">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
 </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
 <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
 </ng-container>

 <!-- Symbol Column -->

  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>`

 <!-- Secondary Column -->

   <ng-container matColumnDef="secondary" >
     <td mat-cell [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length" *matCellDef="let element"> 
        <textarea></textarea>
     </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <button *ngIf="!isEdited" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button> 
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
         <button *ngIf="isEdited" mat-mini-fab class="add-btn" matTooltip="Add comment" color="primary" (click)="addComment(element.position)"
          >+</button>
         <button *ngIf="isEdited" mat-mini-fab class="add-btn" color="warn" (click)="removeComment(element.position)"
          >-</button>
       </td>
  </ng-container>

 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['secondary'];" [style.display]="elementArr[row.position]===1?'':'none'">
 </tr>`

</table>

<div *ngIf="isEdited" class="action-btn">
  <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Add comment" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">Save</button>
</div>
```

**table.component.ts file**

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {name: string;        position: number ;       weight: number;        symbol: string;
}
 const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [{position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},{position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},{position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},{position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},{position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'}];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
   displayedColumns: string[]=["position","name","weight","symbol","actions"];
   dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
   elementArr:any=[].fill(0);
   isEdited:boolean;

   ngOnInit(){}

   onEdit(){
     this.isEdited = true;
   }
   onCancel(){
      this.isEdited = false;
   }
   addComment(position) {
      this.elementArr[position]=1;
   }
   removeComment(position) {
      this.elementArr[position]=0;
   }

}
```